# How to add forecast accuracy to this loop for HoltWinters in R?

Tags: r, loops, data-manipulation, forecasting

A fully reproducible example.

```
library(forecast)
date = seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 48)

productB = rep("B",48)
productB = rep("B",48)
productA = rep("A",48)
productA = rep("A",48)

subproducts1=rep("1",48)
subproducts2=rep("2",48)
subproductsx=rep("x",48)
subproductsy=rep("y",48)

b1 <- c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
b2 <- c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
b3 <-c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
b4 <- c(rnorm(30,5), rep(0,18))
```

Created the dataframe below

```
dfone <- data.frame("date"= rep(date,4),
            "product"= c(rep(productB,2),rep(productA,2)),
            "subproduct"= 
c(subproducts1,subproducts2,subproductsx,subproductsy),
            "actuals"= c(b1,b2,b3,b4))

export_df <- split(dfone[1:4], dfone[3])
```

## Creation of data frames based off UNIQUE SUBPRODUCTS

```
dummy_list <- split(dfone[1:4], dfone[3]) %>% lapply( function(x) 
x[(names(x) %in% c("date", "actuals"))])
dummy_list <-  lapply(dummy_list, function(x) { x["date"] <- NULL; x })


list_dfs <- list()
for (i in 1:length(unique(dfone$subproduct))) {
  #assign(paste0("df", i), as.data.frame(dummy_list[[i]]))
  list_dfs <-append(list_dfs,dummy_list[[i]])
}

combined_dfs <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE,  
by='date'), list(list_dfs))
```

Creating the time series

```
list_ts <- lapply(list_dfs, function(t) 
ts(t,start=c(2019,1),end=c(2021,6), frequency = 12)) %>%
  lapply( function(t) ts_split(t,sample.out=(0.2*length(t))))    # 
creates my train test split
list_ts <- do.call("rbind", list_ts)  #Creates a list of time series
```

Creation of many lists of time series. In this case creates 729 objects in the global environment.

```
n1 <- seq(0.1, 0.99, by = 0.1)
n2 <- seq(0.1, 0.99, by = 0.1)
n3 <- seq(0.1, 0.99, by = 0.1)

dat_n <- expand.grid(n1 = n1, n2= n2, n3 = n3) 
out<- lapply(seq_len(nrow(dat_n)), function(i) {
   c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative <- lapply(list_ts[1: 
(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x) 
       forecast::forecast(HoltWinters(x,seasonal = "additive",alpha = 
dat_n$n1[i],beta=dat_n$n2[i],gamma=dat_n$n3[i])))
    c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative <- 
 lapply(c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative, "[", "mean")
  assign(paste0("c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative", i), 
c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative, envir = .GlobalEnv)
 c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative})
```

I want to add the function below, where I can test each list object's training model data with accuracy for the test data and based off RMSE (list_ts[[4]] is the training and the test is list_ts[[8]] because there is 4 unique subproducts, it is 4+4=8.)

```
 forecast::accuracy(forecast::forecast(HoltWinters(list_ts[[4]],
 seasonal="multiplicative",alpha=.1,beta=.1,gamma=.2),h=24),list_ts[[8]])

        ME     RMSE      MAE         MPE      MAPE      MASE        ACF1 Theil's U
Training set    86.77923 2325.705 1476.658   -5.382147  32.47896 0.5611823 -0.05022049        
 NA
Test set     -3165.29871 6126.887 5389.800 -102.314548 129.32404 2.0483154  0.33876651  
 2.446896
```

The goal is to instead of having 729 objects, I want only 1 model object with the best RMSE on the test data for example.

Edit1: Take this out from the code above for now to use accuracy.

```
 c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative <- 
     lapply(c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative, "[", "mean")
```

Edit2: fixed the code
This will now work and c_triple... is 1-4 and list_ts is 5-8 always.

```
forecast::accuracy(c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative1[[1]],
 list_ts[[5]])[4] # pulls out the RMSE
```

When we find the lowest RMSE we want to add back the mean function to create the model to the glb environment

Edit3:

```
dat_n <- expand.grid(n1 = n1, n2= n2, n3 = n3) 
out<- lapply(seq_len(nrow(dat_n)), function(i) {
  c_triple_holtwinters_additive <- lapply(list_ts[1: 
(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x) 
      forecast::forecast(HoltWinters(x,seasonal = "additive",alpha = 
dat_n$n1[i],beta=dat_n$n2[i],gamma=dat_n$n3[i])))
 #    c_triple_holtwinters_additive <- 
 # lapply(c_triple_holtwinters_additive, "[", "mean")
 assign(paste0("c_triple_holtwinters_additive", i), 
c_triple_holtwinters_additive, envir = .GlobalEnv)
 c_triple_holtwinters_additive})

forecast::accuracy(c_triple_holtwinters_additive1[[1]],list_ts[[5]])[4]
```

Comment: Is the question you are looking

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you

Comment: in the 'out' data which one is 'test' and train

Comment: (list_ts[1: (length(list_ts)/2)] would be only train. Remove the /2 and it is the entire thing. The training data is list_ts[[1]] to 4 (because we have four unique subproducts, can be 6,10,12, etc). Test data will always be list_ts[[i+(#unique_subproducts)]] (this is the the training data with corresponding test data. Notice how the forecast::accuracy function is using the training data for model creation and comparing it to it's test data list_ts[[8]]

Comment: Is the list_ts or out you want to work with

Comment: List_ts I believe. Just to make sure, I want to add the forecast accuracy function for all 729 models and only create to global environment the best model (1 model) based off lowest RMSE. If it is easier, we do the original code, and do the forecasting accuracy to all 729 models and compare after, and delete the objects that isn't the best? Idk if that's possible

Comment: Do you need `apply(list_ts, 1, FUN = function(x) forecast::accuracy(forecast::forecast(HoltWinters(x$train,
  seasonal="multiplicative",alpha=.1,beta=.1,gamma=.2),h=24),x$test))`

Comment: I do need forecast::accuracy() yes, but I think the parameters for alpha beta gamma should be changing along with n1,n2,n3 I believe.

Comment: I guess that would be from `dat_n`, but if you are looping over train, test from list_ts, wouldn't that be 729* 4

Comment: Just to make sure, the forecast::accuracy() alpha beta and gamma should be corresponding to the ones in dat_n. This is checking to see how well the model we created to global env has done. The training data from length(list_ts[[i}])/2 creates 729 objects. If we compare our 729 model objects to our test data, that would also create 729 forecasting accuracies.

Comment: If it is easier, we can split list_ts[[]] into training_ts[[]] and test_ts[[]] by half so we have the same index for both? In that case I would need to combine them again at the end I believe

Comment: so, what is `out` here.  If you chek your code, `list_ts` is of length 8

Comment: I'm not quite sute to be honest. I think it helps to loop through the rows in the dat_n. It seems like that is the index for the function. Yes list_ts is of length 8 in this example(list_ts[[1-4]] is training and list_ts[[5-8]] would be test, my new data it is 20, because I have 10 unique subproducts.

Comment: I see that `length(out)` is 729.  Are you using the elements from out or not

Comment: Outside of using it for this function for dat_n I have no need for it. Don't we need it to create the 729 models?

Comment: you have created 729 objects as well `c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative`.  From this, I am not sure which one should be training/test

Comment: Ok let's make it easy. If list_ts has 8 elements, if we split this into the first 4 elements for train_ts and last 4 elements for test_ts that would be train test. list_ts[1: 
(length(list_ts)/2)] is training only since we only use index 1-4 since list_ts is 8 elements

Comment: ok, that part I understand, but remember your alpha, beta, etc in dat_n is for 729 models i.e. each row corresponds to particular model

Comment: In that simple case, how may rows will be there for dat_n

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand. Dat_n has 729 rows for 729 models. What do you mean how many rows will there be for dat_n. If you are talking about forecast_accuracy() there should be 729 outputs

Comment: I meant in your accuracy model, you are using `list_ts[[4]]` and `list_ts[[8]]` with `729` models, I am not sure which element should go into the pace for 4 and 8

Comment: So before we apply the lapply(...mean) each c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative will have 4 elements containing models for each of the training. The corresponding test data from list_ts[[]] would be list_ts[[5,6,7,8]]. So I believe actually list_ts[[4]] should be looping through each new object created so c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative[[1,2,3,4]] and list_ts[[8]] can be static where list_ts[[5-8]]

Comment: I am thinking tha tyou need ` Map(function(x, y)
 
   forecast::accuracy(forecast::forecast(HoltWinters(x$mean,
   seasonal="multiplicative",alpha = 
dat_n$n1[i],beta=dat_n$n2[i],gamma=dat_n$n3[i]),h=24), y ),
              c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative,  list_ts[5:8]
           )` in the loop

Comment: When I tried your logic.  I get an error `Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end'`.  Is the logic correct

Comment: Updating the post

Comment: Oh okay. I'll try to work it out

Comment: It still returns `Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end'
In addition: Warning message:
In window.default(x, ...) : 'start' value not changed`

Comment: try this code and check `lapply(seq_len(nrow(dat_n[1:5, ])), function(i) {
   c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative <- lapply(list_ts[1: 
(length(list_ts)/2)], function(x) 
       forecast::forecast(HoltWinters(x,seasonal = "additive",alpha = 
dat_n$n1[i],beta=dat_n$n2[i],gamma=dat_n$n3[i])))

 c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative <- 
      lapply(c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative, "[", "mean")

Comment: Map(function(x, y)
 
    forecast::accuracy(forecast::forecast(HoltWinters(x$mean,
    seasonal="multiplicative",alpha = 
 dat_n$n1[i],beta=dat_n$n2[i],gamma=dat_n$n3[i]),h=24), y ),
               c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative,  list_ts[5:8]
            )

   })`

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add the 1 after the model name. You would need to remove the lapply(c_triple_holtwinters_multiplicative, "[", "mean")  from the original post to make it work. I need it again after for the best model however.

Comment: Trying above codes

Comment: My code does exactly as you have showed.  It loops over corresponding elements to do the accuracy

Comment: Can you format it as an answer so I can upvote your post, Does it return the modell with the best acccuracy I need to fix the codes

Comment: NOw, that code is giving the error as I descrbed above

Comment: I made a new edit with different names, and the idea of what I need. It works for me. It is okay if you don't want to work on this. It seems complex

Comment: This part you mentioned is giving error `forecast::accuracy(c_triple_holtwinters_additive1[[1]],list_ts[[5]])[4]`

Comment: It returns 3972.146 for me. Try with my edit3: where I commented out the mean. If it doesn't work it's okay

Comment: ` c_triple_holtwinters_additive <- lapply(list_ts[1: 
  (length(list_ts)/2)], function(x) 
        forecast::forecast(HoltWinters(x,seasonal = "additive",alpha = 
  dat_n$n1[i],beta=dat_n$n2[i],gamma=dat_n$n3[i])))

 c_triple_holtwinters_additive <- 
      lapply(c_triple_holtwinters_additive, "[", "mean")
    
     Map(function(x, y)
 
    forecast::accuracy(forecast::forecast(HoltWinters(x$mean,
    seasonal="multiplicative",alpha = 
 dat_n$n1[i],beta=dat_n$n2[i],gamma=dat_n$n3[i]),h=24), y ),
               c_triple_holtwinters_additive,  list_ts[5:8]
            )`

Comment: can you try this code within the loop

Comment: There is some symbol error, sorry I am getting confused with the syntax it is very long

Comment: what is the additive1

Comment: It is one of the 729 models that is created. Do you mind formatting the solution into an answer? I'm not sure why it's not running

Comment: Earlier, i was using the mean object and that is the reason it didn't work.  Sorry, got confused by the obejctes created

Comment: Yes it is very confusing with the names I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
out1 <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(dat_n)), function(i) {
    c_triple_holtwinters_additive <- lapply(list_ts[1: 
  (length(list_ts)/2)], function(x) 
        forecast::forecast(HoltWinters(x,seasonal = "additive",alpha = 
  dat_n$n1[i],beta=dat_n$n2[i],gamma=dat_n$n3[i])))

    c_triple_holtwinters_additive1 <- 
         lapply(c_triple_holtwinters_additive, "[", "mean")
    
    acc1 <- unlist(Map(function(x, y)

         forecast::accuracy(x,y )[4],
                 c_triple_holtwinters_additive,  list_ts[5:8]
              ))
    ind1 <- which.min(acc1)
    nm1 <- paste0("c_triple_holtwinters_additive", i)
    
    
     assign(nm1[ind1], 
        c_triple_holtwinters_additive1[[ind1]], envir = .GlobalEnv)

    c_triple_holtwinters_additive1[[ind1]]
   })
```

-checking

```
head(out1, 5)
[[1]]
[[1]]$mean
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
2021 3.992136 4.551152 4.819030 2.722871 3.429581 5.088622 3.169820 5.611467 5.198844 3.475341 3.554109 5.348270
2022 3.335633 3.894648 4.162526 2.066368 2.773077 4.432118 2.513316 4.954963 4.542341 2.818837 2.897606 4.691766


[[2]]
[[2]]$mean
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
2021 3.973570 4.537064 4.810701 2.720144 3.431003 5.093744 3.176812 5.638199 5.244988 3.506140 3.572943 5.374759
2022 3.363802 3.927296 4.200934 2.110376 2.821235 4.483976 2.567044 5.028431 4.635220 2.896372 2.963175 4.764991


[[3]]
[[3]]$mean
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
2021 4.045785 4.619027 4.903568 2.823377 3.542898 5.213984 3.303773 5.790314 5.418427 3.663552 3.723406 5.541533
2022 3.546085 4.119327 4.403867 2.323676 3.043197 4.714283 2.804073 5.290613 4.918727 3.163851 3.223705 5.041832


[[4]]
[[4]]$mean
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
2021 4.126131 4.707987 5.002172 2.930755 3.657247 5.335301 3.430712 5.941848 5.587022 3.810281 3.864567 5.703121
2022 3.722981 4.304837 4.599022 2.527605 3.254097 4.932151 3.027563 5.538699 5.183873 3.407132 3.461417 5.299972


[[5]]
[[5]]$mean
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
2021 4.171013 4.757059 5.056343 2.988862 3.717521 5.398159 3.495038 6.027034 5.681583 3.874808 3.923682 5.783772
2022 3.811419 4.397465 4.696749 2.629268 3.357928 5.038565 3.135444 5.667440 5.321989 3.515214 3.564088 5.424178
```

Comment: Ok to add from this, can I now find the lowest value from the output and give me the model from row of dat_n in my global environment?

Comment: @chriswang123456 do you want the updatd one

Comment: Testing right now. So to make sure while it is running, is this creating 729 models and finding the lowest RMSE model to return to me?

Comment: The name comes out as NA instead of c_triple.... and also is there a possibility to return in a list of 4 elements the mean values for the best rmse for list_ts[[1],2,3,4 etc? This is the final step

Comment: There is a typo for `ind1`

Comment: This is very good. Is there a way to return one list of 4 elements with the best RMSE mean values? Basically like how the code ran in my original post before all the edits. So for out[[1]] a=.1,b=.3,g=.3 and out[[2]] a=.3,b=.5,g=.8.. etc  for example

Comment: @chriswang123456 you want to print the dat_n values corresponding or not?

Comment: @chriswang123456 but when we tried the multiplicative, there was an error

Comment: I understand that dat_n corresponds to the out list's parameters. For me, c_triple_holtwinters_additive[ind1] does not come out to the global environment

Comment: Have you tried ion a fresh R session with all objects removed from env

Comment: Yeah, the only thing that comes out is NA. which is a list of  1 element of mean values. I expect the output to be a list (named cw_.....) of 4 mean values one for each list_ts[[1]],list_ts[[2]],list_ts[[3]],list_ts[[4]],

Comment: Are you saying that you are not able to get the output as I showed

Comment: I can get the output you show, I just thought it would be named cw_... like how it was with my original code. Also I think i didn't explain too clearly.. because I was getting confused too

Comment: that is created in the global env

Comment: For me only a list named NA comes out. I don't know if it was intended, but I thought the output would be a list of 4 elements, the best parameters (best dat_n row) for each training data. I'm sorry if i didn't explain too clearly. My brain was hurting doing this lol

Comment: Btw maybe i'm the confused one.. Is this a separate solution or supposed to be combined with my original? Nvmfor sure it is separate

Comment: I got the issue.  It is that the `i` created is from the outer loop while the `acc1` is giving accuracy from within each of the loop inside

Comment: so how would I fix this

Comment: If ind1 gives an index of 2 or more, the `nm1` is just a single value and thus it returns NA because that index is not available.

Comment: Ok got it. Is there a way to take the parameters for the best RMSE and apply it to the 4 training data in list_ts[[]] in the loop? and return an object in the environment? If you want I can make a new question for this

Comment: @chriswang123456 can you make a new question as there are lots of comments in this